# The Smell of Incense - where's the quest giver?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I am looking for the quest giver for the Smell of Incense. I have been wandering about Flotsam and yet to meet the quest giver. How do I start the quest?

Comment: What part of Flotsam have you been wandering around? IIRC, you need to be by the harbor to start this quest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

His name is "Vencel Pugg", and I found him near the docks.  In my case he was leaning on a wall in a corner of the boardwalk behind (North of) the Inn.  Lower level, down the stairs.  He'll ask very generically, something like "are you willing to do some work for money?" without elaborating as to the nature of the work.